# How to open a new browser tab with locked address bar?

Tags: javascript, url, tabs, locked, address-bar

I am able to open a new browser window with locked address bar using this code.

```
window.open('example.com', 'mysite', 'width=800,height=600,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=no');
```

It works well in all major browsers.

Is it possible to open a new (locked) **tab**, instead of a window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: @Towkir — I don't think that is a good duplicate because the focus of the question is on the locked address bar, rather than the new tab.

Comment: Since you said _Nothing an author can do can choose to open in a new tab instead of a new window_ ,  I think it is, because if you can't open a new tab, there is no option of a locked address bar, also, the OP already achieved the locked address bar on a new window.

Comment: Both of you are probably right - although this is not a 'perfect' duplicate, the answer @Quentin provided in that question pretty much sums up that it actually isn't possible. In fact, I have never seen a browser tab with locked address bar alongside with other tabs opened. Only single window. Have you?